# Display unchanged files in git diff

Tags: git, diff

I am comparing a path on two branches with git to prepare for merge. I want to list all files under this path, and their status with `git diff`, not only changed files.

Example:

I have a repository, currently on branch `main`, which has 3 files:

```
$ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ ls -1
a.file
b.file
c.file
```

On a second branch `new-branch`, I perform three changes:

- delete `b.file`
- change `c.file`
- create `d.file`

```
$ git status
On branch new-branch
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ ls -1
a.file
c.file
d.file
```

Using `git diff` I can list the names and statuses of all changed files:

```
$ git diff --name-status main new-branch
D       b.file
M       c.file
A       d.file
```

This is *almost* exactly what I want: I would also like to find `a.file` in this list. Something like this:

```
        a.file
D       b.file
M       c.file
A       d.file
```

Is this possible with `git diff`? Perhaps with `git show`?

Answer (score 2):

Please use following code.

```
git ls-files | while read -r line;
do
    st=$(git diff --name-status main new-branch "$line");
    if [ -n "$st" ]; then
        echo "$st";
    else
        echo "   $line";
    fi;
done
```

`git ls-files`: show all files controlled by Git.

`git diff --name-status main new-branch "$line"` We will use git diff for specific file.

Note: You just need to paste the above code into terminal.

Comment: @LodeRunner. Do you have any difficulty applying my solution?